# Google Maps - Link from static image with markers to full maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I need to redirect from a static google maps image via the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps) to maps.google.com.

I have multiple markers on the map. Example: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=235x227&maptype=roadmap&markers=37.970982,23.724559|37.971487,23.724953|37.973291,23.726862"

[image]

I need the proper url format that, when the image is clicked, will redirect to maps.google.com with all markers placed on the map. I cant find the documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no way to add markers into the google maps now.. so the answer is no.

However, you can build a custom page, which uses the google maps API and you can add markers that way.

I built a sample page here in [github](https://github.com/kylelam/kylelam.github.io/blob/master/SO/customMarkers.html).

so for your map:

[image]

you can wrap it with an `a` element which link to your page with the same option like this sample:
http://kylelam.github.io/SO/customMarkers.html?size=235x227&maptype=roadmap&markers=37.970982,23.724559|37.971487,23.724953|37.973291,23.726862

Comment: I had a bad feeling that that was the case. Thanks for the idea and the thoroughness.